# Rails3 not reloading code in lib while in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autoload

**THE SITUATION:**

1. I have code in `lib/foo/bar.rb` with a simple method defined as such:

   ```
   module Foo
     class Bar
       def test
         "FooBar"
       end
     end
   end
   ```
2. In my helper, `FooBarHelper`, I have:

   ```
   require `lib/foo/bar`
   module FooBarHelper
     def test_foo_bar
       fb = Foo::Bar.new
       fb.test
     end
   end
   ```
3. In my view, I call this helper method like so:

   ```
   <%= test_foo_bar =>
   ```
4. In my `config/environments/development.rb`, I added the directory to my `config.autoload_paths`:

   ```
   config.autoload_paths += ["#{config.root}/lib/foo"]
   ```

---

**THE PROBLEM:**

When I change the return value of `Foo::Bar.test` to, for example, `"MODIFIED FOOBAR"`, the original return value, `"FooBar"`, is still being displayed on the view and not the new value.

Since I'm in development mode, shouldn't the code reload the code on every request?

Could someone tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They removed the `lib` folder the app root in Rails 3.

You can either add it back

```
config.autoload_paths << 'lib'
```

or you can use `require_dependency` in your helper.

```
module FooBarHelper
  require_dependency 'foo/bar'

  def test_foo_bar
    fb = Foo::Bar.new
    fb.test
  end
end
```

Both ways tell Rails that your file `lib/foo/bar.rb` should be autoloaded and subsequently, reloaded each request.

Comment: Thanks for the response Samuel! Aren't I already using your first suggestion? Should I be using the `<<` operator instead fo `+=`? I thought they were equivalent.

Comment: For your purpose, they are the same. The difference is you want `lib` to be autoloaded for it to be able to find the `foo/bar.rb` source file for the constant `Foo::Bar`.

Comment: I updated THE SITUATION section of my post to make it easier to pick apart. See Part 4.

Comment: So are you saying that I can't or shouldn't be using a more-resolved path in my `autoload_paths` (i.e., `lib/foo` vs `lib`)? I should also make it clear that autoloading is not the issue, but rather reloading when a change has been made to Bar class. Since I'm in development mode, shouldn't it reload the code on every request?

Comment: Exactly. If you want to use the rails auto class name mapping to filename, `Foo::Bar` must map to `foo/bar.rb` which it can only find if your `lib` folder is in the load path (`$:` or `LOAD_PATH`). --- Not all code gets reloaded on each request (the rails framework for example) and one big change was to remove the `lib` folder from the reloaded files.

Comment: Let me give this a shot... but what if I don't want everything in the `lib` folder autoloaded? Also, should I remove `#{config.root}`?

Comment: So I replaced `config.autoload_paths += ["#{config.root}/lib/foo"]` with `config.autoload_paths += ["lib"]`, restarted my app, refreshed my view, it displayed `FooBar`. Changed the return value of my method to `Modified FooBar`, refreshed my view, and it still displayed `FooBar`...

Comment: Do you still have a `require` statement? Rails doesn't stop you from requiring files and preventing it from reloading them (think libraries that you didn't write). If you use autoload, you cannot use require and must let rails do it. Otherwise use `require_dependency` if you don't want to autoload the lib folder.

Comment: Nice! Will `require_dependency` auto-reload? I also managed to apply what you stated about the auto-class mapping so that I don't have to autoload the entire `lib` folder by simply creating another folder `foo_lib` and putting `foo` inside of it. Question: Where did you read about this stuff? Because I would definitely like to read more about it.

Comment: `require_dependency` is a helper in rails to specifically load something and mark it as reloadable.

Comment: Thanks Samuel. You've been a great help! Can I ask where you read about the auto class name mapping stuff?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a document on it, but the relevant methods are underscore (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-underscore) and camelize (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-camelize).

Comment: Thanks Samuel! Really appreciate all the help.

Comment: Hi Samuel, I hope you're still around. This convention works fine for classes, but does not work for Modules (i.e., Mixins). I've been reading that Rails treats folders like namespaces, and therefore maps module names to folders. So how do I go about autoloading an actual module/mixin? (i.e., `module Mixins::MyMixin` in `lib/mixins/my_mixin.rb`)

Comment: Autoloading a module is no different than a class, it should work fine. You can always see what rails will be looking for with `"Mixins::MyMixin".underscore # => "mixins/my_mixin"`.

Answer (score 25):

Previous answers does not work. Here is a working one: http://ileitch.github.com/2012/03/24/rails-32-code-reloading-from-lib.html

You have to use both:

```
config.watchable_dirs['lib'] = [:rb]
```

and

```
require_dependency
```

but any `config.autoload_paths` based solution won't work in Rails ~> 3.2

Comment: I definitely think this should be the accepted solution. I spent the last half hour search for this because autoloading the entire `lib` dir just felt dirty.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Mike. The problem is that the first answer was given at the time when Rails 3.1 was available. However, I acknowledge your answer is also correct. I've given you an up-vote, but perhaps you could create a new question for Rails > 3.2 and answer it yourself.

Comment: I put `config.watchable_dirs['lib'] = [:rb]` in development.rb and in my controller I used `require_dependency "my_folder\my_class"` to reference my class in `lib\my_folder\my_class`. See http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveSupport/Dependencies/Loadable/require_dependency for more.

Comment: I upvoted this because it unearthed a rarely mentioned config option (`watchable_dirs`). However, it doesn't work for me in Rails 4.0.0.  If I omit `config.autoload_paths`, it can't even find the libraries, and you don't explain how you tell Rails where to look instead of via `autoload_paths`.  Do you mess with `$:` or something?  Furthermore, I get `superclass mismatch for class` errors with `require_dependency`.

Comment: OK, I pinned this down to weirdness resulting from subclassing `Struct.new(...)`.  Once I eliminated that, autoloading and reloading all worked great simply by setting `config.autoload_paths`.

Answer (score 2):

Autoloading code from the lib folder was intentionally disabled in rails3, see this [ticket](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5218-rails-3-rc-does-not-autoload-from-lib) for more details.

The workaround suggested by Samuel is a great start, however I found that certain environments still had difficulty finding the libraries in a testing environment (say being invoked from a cucumber scenario), and that including the root path, as suggested within the [ticket](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5218-rails-3-rc-does-not-autoload-from-lib#ticket-5218-12) and hinted by the original comment in application.rb was a more robust approach:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you putting the require into the module, when using autoload_path you should not need to require the file at all, it should be working without, I think if you manually require the file afterwards, rails does not know when to load it again?

Something like this:

```
require `bar`

module FooBarHelper

  def test_foo_bar
    fb = Foo::Bar.new
    fb.test
  end

end
```

should work, no need for having the require inside your module.

Comment: Thanks for the response Max! Appreciate it! So how do you propose I access my Bar class?

Comment: I have updated my above answer, does that work for you with reloading?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, if you have /lib/foo in your load path you only need to require bar in the file. I corrected my example.