# What to do with my monolithic model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, model

My user model is about 2k lines of code.  I'm sure this is the case for lots of apps.  However, readability and even maintainability starts to degrade in models beyond 400 lines of code, in my opinion.  So I started to take related code in the user model and organize it in modules in lib.  For example, if I had code related to the user's friends, then I created a module called UserFriend and included it in the user model.

Doing this helped solve the original problem.  However, the downside is every time I modify code in the module in my dev environment, I gotta restart the server to load it.

So:

1. Is my original approach to
   handling the monolithic model
   correct?
2. What can I do to avoid
   having to restart my server to load
   code changes in user modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few solutions floating around the Internet for how to reload the `lib` folder automatically in development mode.

[One post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018757/rails3-not-reloading-code-in-lib-while-in-development-mode/4020357#4020357) I found said that if you require files using `require_dependency` instead of `require`, the file will be reloaded each request.

Another more "hacky" solution [can be found here](http://hemju.com/2011/02/11/rails-3-quicktip-auto-reload-lib-folders-in-development-mode/), and involves adding a `before_filter` to your `ApplicationController`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing, Just keep your helper modules in model folder itself instead of keeping in in lib folder OR create a folder in model where you can keep all the helper modules. I don't see any problem with this approach.